# Memory Exhausted due to PHP loop through query data

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, pdo

I have some code that loops through the data received from DB, but the problem is that memory is exhausted. My memory limit is set at 128 MB.  The total rows returned for my test are about 200k. So I don't know if it's just too much data or if there's a way to buffer the table and not store the whole thing in the memory at once.

The memory exhausted error is thrown at line where the while statement starts.

```
    $queryResult = $dbCon->prepare( $sqlQuery );
    $queryResult -> bindParam(':field1', $field1);
    $queryResult -> bindParam(':field2', $field2);
    $queryResult -> bindParam(':field3', $field3);
    $queryResult -> execute();
    $allData = array();
    $i=0;
    while ( $row = $queryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
    {
        foreach ( $row as $sKey=>$vVal )
        {
            if( $i == 0 )
            {
                $this->allHeaders[] = $sKey ;
            }
            $allData[ $i ][ $sKey ] = $vVal;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: You should have asked "How to handle 200k(+) rows" ... or not.

Comment: Buffer for what? Do you need all of the data at the same time, or are you just going to be processing something from each row and then throwing away everything else?

Answer (score 0):

two problems here :

- assignment in while-statement ... thats bad practice and WILL cause problems
- direct foreach-iteration over SQL-resultsets, even though you appear to use some abstraction-layer ... this CAN work but i wouldnt recommend it

If you want to avoid the memory-problem (how big is your DB? several GB, i assume ...) you simply need to split the result-set into chunks (see SQL-"LIMIT" statement) OR iterate only after your last result has been processed - hence you could do everything which needs to be done within one single iteration

Answer (score 0):

To get around the problem of crashing, create an .htaccess file and add the following line

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

Note: You can use values powers of 2 (2**2, 2**3, 2**4. ...)

However, changing the memory limit is shifting the problem. The source of the problem is the massive memory being used. You might find the program will just crash later if it has more memory.

Try using fetchAll() and see if makes a difference

```
$rows = $queryResult->fetchAll();
```